# Wpf + Cefsharp Desktop application

Tags: wpf, cefsharp

Newbie question about WPF applications.
I'm trying to create a wpf desktop app that opens an external website in a Webviewer. I'm using cefsharp to do this. How can I get the user to stay logged in after first successful login? The username-password authentication is handled by the the website(external) itself.
The login should persist even when the app is closed and relaunched.
Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Search the web for CefSharp Cookies.

Comment: By default an in memory cache is used. To persist cookies to disk you need to specify a CachePath,  see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#cefsettings-and-browsersettings there is a working example at https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample/blob/cefsharp/86/CefSharp.MinimalExample.Wpf/App.xaml.cs#L16